# Marklogic Data Hub Framework 2.x Deploy Failure

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

mlDeploy failure while trying to install data hub framework using gradle

I'm trying to install DHF 2.0.6 over MarkLogic 9.0-5 server (community edition) on Windows 10. I'm able to perform "gradlew -PenvironmentName=local hubInit -i" but "gradle mlDeploy" fails with the below error. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
:hubPreInstallCheck
com.marklogic.hub.PreInstallCheck@1f9cba88:mlGradleDeleteModuleTimestampsFile
Deleting G:\ODH\Development\EODH\build\ml-javaclient-util\module-timestamps.properties

:mlDeleteModuleTimestampsFile
:mlPrepareRestApiDependencies
:mlGradleLoadModules
Exception in thread "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1" com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: failed to apply resource at documents: Bad Request. Server Message: XDMP-NOSUCHDB: No such database data-hub-MODULES
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.checkStatus(OkHttpServices.java:4317)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3381)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postBulkDocuments(OkHttpServices.java:3461)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:614)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.GenericDocumentImpl.write(GenericDocumentImpl.java:23)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:606)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.GenericDocumentImpl.write(GenericDocumentImpl.java:23)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:590)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.GenericDocumentImpl.write(GenericDocumentImpl.java:23)
        at com.marklogic.client.ext.batch.DefaultBatchHandler.handleBatch(DefaultBatchHandler.java:48)
        at com.marklogic.client.ext.batch.RestBatchWriter$1.run(RestBatchWriter.java:74)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
:mlDeployApp
Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"400", "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD", "message":"MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD: (err:FOER0000) Payload has errors in structure, content-type or values. Payload malformed: ADMIN-INVALIDCONFIG: (err:FOER0000) Invalid configuration:  '384' is not a valid in-memory-triple-index-size"}}
:mlDeployApp FAILED
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    // This plugin allows you to create different environments
    // for your gradle deploy. Each environment is represented
    // by a gradle-${env}.properties file
    // See https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin
    // specify the env on the command line with:
    // gradle -PenvironmentName=x ...
    id 'net.saliman.properties' version '1.4.6'

    // This gradle plugin extends the ml-gradle plugin with
    // commands that make the Data Hub Framework do its magic
    id 'com.marklogic.ml-data-hub' version '2.0.6'
}

// These tasks work round an issue whereby the DHF does not seem to replace tokens in modules
//
// The mlGradleLoadModules task uses the base ml-gradle
// LoadModulesTask to load modules from src/main/ml-modules/.  Put
// modules in which you need tokens replaced (for example config
// modules) into src/main/ml-modules.
task mlGradleLoadModules(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.client.LoadModulesTask) {
  dependsOn mlPrepareRestApiDependencies
  mustRunAfter mlClearModulesDatabase
}
mlLoadModules.dependsOn mlGradleLoadModules
mlDeployApp.dependsOn mlGradleLoadModules

// The mlGradleDeleteModuleTimestampsFile ensures that the timestamps
// file gets deleted as and when required so that modules in
// src/main/ml-modules get reloaded when required.
task mlGradleDeleteModuleTimestampsFile(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.DeleteModuleTimestampsFileTask)
mlDeleteModuleTimestampsFile.dependsOn mlGradleDeleteModuleTimestampsFile
```

gradle.properties:

```
# These settings are used by the Data Hub Framework when
# communicating with MarkLogic.
# The values in this file are meant as project-wide settings.
# You can override these properties for a specific environment
# by creating a gradle-{environment}.properties file.
# For example, to create a properties file for your prod environment create a file
# named gradle-prod.properties.
#
# ....
mlHost=localhost

# Your MarkLogic Username and Password
mlUsername=<uid>
mlPassword=<pwd>


mlOdbcserverName=data-hub-SQL
mlOdbcPort=5432
mlOdbcDbName=data-hub-SQLDB
mlOdbcForestsPerHost=4
mlOdbcAuth=basic

mlStagingAppserverName=data-hub-STAGING
mlStagingPort=8010
mlStagingDbName=data-hub-STAGING
mlStagingForestsPerHost=4
mlStagingAuth=digest
# To enable SSL for staging
mlStagingSimpleSsl=true

mlFinalAppserverName=data-hub-FINAL
mlFinalPort=8011
mlFinalDbName=data-hub-FINAL
mlFinalForestsPerHost=4
mlFinalAuth=digest
# To enable SSL for final
mlFinalSimpleSsl=true

mlTraceAppserverName=data-hub-TRACING
mlTracePort=8012
mlTraceDbName=data-hub-TRACING
mlTraceForestsPerHost=1
mlTraceAuth=digest
# To enable SSL for trace
# mlTraceSimpleSsl=true

mlJobAppserverName=data-hub-JOBS
mlJobPort=8013
mlJobDbName=data-hub-JOBS
mlJobForestsPerHost=1
mlJobAuth=digest
# To enable SSL for jobs
# mlJobSimpleSsl=true

mlModulesDbName=data-hub-MODULES
mlModulesForestsPerHost=1

mlTriggersDbName=data-hub-TRIGGERS
mlTriggersForestsPerHost=1

mlSchemasDbName=data-hub-SCHEMAS
mlSQLSchemasDbName=data-hub-SQL-SCHEMAS
mlSchemasForestsPerHost=1

# You can override this to specify an alternate folder for your
# custom forest info. Defaults to user-config/forests/
# mlCustomForestPath=forests

# The name of the Role to create for Hub Access
mlHubUserRole=data-hub-role
mlHubUserName=data-hub-user
```

gradle-local.properties:

```
# Put your overrides from gradle.properties here
# Don't check this in to version control

mlHost=localhost

mlUsername=<uid>
mlPassword=<uid>

mlStagingAuth=basic
mlFinalAuth=basic

# mlAppServicesAuthentication=digest

mlExternalSecurity=LDAPConfig

mlTestRestPort=8015
mlTestRestServerName=data-hub-TEST
```

Comment: There is a clear error message: `Invalid configuration:  '384' is not a valid in-memory-triple-index-size"`. Did you check the configs for that property? Is it inserted as string instead of as number perhaps?

Comment: I added the configurations (build.gradle, gradle.properties, gradle-local.properties) now. which property you refer? It seems internal to data hub framework and the error comes while doing mlDeploy after the successful hubInit.

Comment: Try running "gradle -i mlDeploy" - that'll show the command that fails, along with what file fails. "in memory triple index size" is a setting on a database, so look at that property setting in the database file that fails.